# Align to the right?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am trying to align the last element in a list to the right:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li id="right">right?</li>
</ul>

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
ul {
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li#right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

It does not work so I guess I am misunderstanding something fundamentally. But what?

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/b22g7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/er3Dw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely position the last element to achieve what you want without having to apply any clearfix to correct issues caused by float.

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
li#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b22g7/3/)

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. The combination of position:relative on the parent and position:absolute on the element does the trick! (Is there any problem with using position:relative like this?)

Comment: @Leo No, the element is already relatively positioned.  It must be specifically stated to allow the absolutely positioned child element (li#right) to absolutely position relative to the parent (ul) and not the window.

Comment: I see, thanks. That explicitly stating of position:relative was something I missed.

Comment: Hm, though this still has one of the disadvantages I wanted to avoid by not using float: It steps out of the containing box. (In my case that makes the CSS a bit more complicated.)

Comment: @Leo Do you have a fiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: I don't have fiddle for this and I think I have found a reasonable solution with yours and others help. I am playing with a layout in Wordpress. Not that I in satisfied with it, but it is a huge problem for me when I can't test my ideas. If I have to go into the technical details to often I lose control over how things look (or my impression of it). If you look at any post here you can see what I am playing with: http://ourcomments.org/psyblog/our-zotero-library/. Look at the menus at >600px and <600px. (And I see now I actually have to go back to float... ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` aligns the element's text to the right. Which it is doing. You just can't see it. If you had `blah blah blah<br />blah` in that `<li>` you'd see the alignment clear as day.

If you want the `<li>` itself to be on the right, try using `float:right` but keep in mind that you may need to move it to be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/b22g7/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li id="right">right?</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
}

ul {
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ff3;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

li#right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid float. (Because it causes some problems when resizing and changing the layout.)

Comment: No worries, however any problems it causes should hopefully be managed by the surrounding DIV I included in my fiddle. If not then I hope you find another solution :-)

Comment: Thanks. ;-) - overflow is confusing. Why a div and not directly on the ul here?

Answer (score 0):

You meant `float: right;`  instead of text-align.

text-align will just align the text 'within' the `li`

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to avoid float because it creates some problems.

Comment: You'll need to use a clearfix method most likely then - http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: I think I have a clearfix there, but it does not help when resizing for some reason. Or, I might have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `li:last-child{float:right;}` and remove the id, you don't need it

Comment: Good point about the id, thanks. (Though I am trying to avoid float.)

Comment: Floats are just fine if you don't abuse them. But in this case, if you 'll use the float for the last child, also float the rest of the elements to the left, to avoid `display:inline-block` gaps.